# which wires go where - brown, blue, YG connect with black, brown, blue

Tags: electrical

I am installing a sensor light at home. The plan is to connect the light with a socket/plug rather than directly with mains.

The instructions are

[image]

I read that brown is live, YG is Earth and Blue is Neutral. These are the wire colors in the wiring I am using. The light switch however has black, blue and brown! How should I connect them? Also, the document of the light shows L and N wires but the light actually has 3 wires. So it isn't clear from the document which light connects to which one.

[image]

I tried few combinations and tested with a PAT tester. The tester started beeping when I took it near the unit. I have uploaded the video here - https://youtu.be/fBVeaPDUmdY

This is the light unit - https://www.ledvance.com/consumer/products/luminaires/residential-luminaires/outdoor-luminaires/decorative-outdoor-luminaires/stainless-steel-wall-luminaires-and-bollards-with-indirect-illumination-c9402

Comment: Could you clarify what we're looking at here? Does the white cable with brown/blue/yellow-green wires run inside to the plug? Where does the black wire come from and what is it connected to?

Comment: the white cable does run inside to the plug. I can't see where the black wire comes from inside the light. It is sealed.

Comment: This is the light unit - https://www.ledvance.com/consumer/products/luminaires/residential-luminaires/outdoor-luminaires/decorative-outdoor-luminaires/stainless-steel-wall-luminaires-and-bollards-with-indirect-illumination-c9402

Comment: any idea @brhans ?